# ビルドすると'AdvToolBar.hpp' file not foundというエラーが発生

Tags: c++

Borland C++ Builder6で作成したプロジェクトファイルをC++ Builder 10.3の新規プロジェクトに一部ずつ加えてビルドできるかやっています。

プロジェクトにMain.cpp,Main.h,Main.dfmの3つのファイルを加えてビルドしてみたところ、次のようなエラーが発生しました。

> [bcc32c 致命的エラー] Main.h(13): 'AdvToolBar.hpp' file not found

このエラー内容は、

```
#include "AdvToolBar.hpp"
```

このAdvToolBar.hppというファイルがPC上になくてインクルードできないということでしょうか？
このファイルがあるかどうか確認したり、エラーの回避方法をご教示頂きますよう、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 名前からして、入手されたトライアル版のどこかにあるのでは？インストール先フォルダの中をExplorerのファイル検索等で探してみてください。あれば、そのファイルのあるフォルダをインクルードパスに加えるとかでしょうか。

Comment: TMSはC:\Program Files (x86)\tmssoftware\TMSVCLUIPack RSXE12　こちらのフォルダにインストールされたようです

Comment: このフォルダ内でAdvToolBar.hppを検索してみたところ、C:\Program Files (x86)\tmssoftware\TMSVCLUIPack RSXE12\Win64というパスにはあるようです。

Comment: このパスにアクセスできているか、確認方法などありますでしょうか？

Comment: C++Builderは使ったことが無いのですが、VisualStudioからの類推で言えば、作業中プロジェクトのプロパティといった所にそうした設定がまとまっているのでは？

Comment: [C++ コンパイラ｜ディレクトリと条件定義](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/ja/%EF%BC%BBC%2B%2B_%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A9%EF%BD%9C%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A8%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B6%E5%AE%9A%E7%BE%A9%EF%BC%BD)こちらの”インクルード ファイルの検索パス”でC:\Program Files (x86)\tmssoftware\TMSVCLUIPack RSXE12\Win64　　このパスを追加することで、今回のエラーは消えました。

Answer (score 0):

今回のエラー

> [bcc32c 致命的エラー] Main.h(13): 'AdvToolBar.hpp' file not found

これが回避できた時のスクリーンキャプチャです。忘れないように自分用に画像投稿させて頂きます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]